# Python regex speed - Greedy vs. non-greedy

Tags: python, regex, performance, non-greedy

I am making several regex substitutions in Python along the lines of

```
  \w\s+\w
```

over many large documents. Obviously if I make the regex non-greedy (with a `?`) it won't change what it matches (as `\w` != `\s`) but will it make the code run any faster? 
In other words, with non-greedy regexes does Python work its way from the first character matched onwards rather than from the end of the document back to that character, or is this a naive view?

Comment: Measure it. Most likely not - but measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the pattern you implied?

```
In [15]: s = 'some text   with \tspaces  between'

In [16]: timeit re.sub(r'(\w)(\s+)(\w)', '\\1 \\3', s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.5 us per loop

In [17]: timeit re.sub(r'(\w)(\s+?)(\w)', '\\1 \\3', s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 us per loop
```

Seems to be a pretty small difference here. Only 5 microseconds with the non-greedy,

Using a 500 word lorem-ipsum, with multiple mixed whitespace between every word, I get an 8 ms difference.